# Copy form input field's value before submission

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm guessing I need JS to do this, but here's the situation.

I have the following input box in my form:

```
<%= f.input :goal_text  %>
```

I also have this link further down:

```
<%= link_to "Sign up with Facebook", "http://local.ngrok.com/auth/facebook?g_text=hardcoded" %>
```

What I would like to happen is that when the link is clicked the current value in goal_text gets set in the link. So if a user had typed "this is it" into the textbox and then clicks the link, it would redirect to:

```
"http://local.ngrok.com/auth/facebook?g_text=this is it"
```

Comment: Yes, you need javascript

Comment: Ok good to confirm that at least. Any help on a JS solution? My brain only works in ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you might do it:

```
$('#goal_text').change(function() {
  var goal_text = $('#goal_text').val();
  $('a').attr("href", "http://local.ngrok.com/auth/facebook?g_text="+goal_text);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dnzGt/

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you could do this pretty easily.  Given ids on the input box and the link (model_goal_text - you will need to add one on your link_to <%= link_to "Sign up", "http://local.ngrok...", id: 'signup_link' %>

```
    $('#model_goal_text').change(function() {
        $('#signup_link').attr("href", 'http://local.ngrok.com/auth/facebook?g_text=' + encodeURIComponent($('#model_goal_text').val());`
    });
```

Replace the name of your model above (or right click and inspect the element to see what the id of your input box is).

Comment: Thanks that worked. Think there are some missing quotes and parentheses above though.